# Yahoo mobile layout issues with word-wrap style

Tags: html, css, yahoo, email-templates, word-break

I can't fix an issue with yahoo email template in the mobile browser. By default yahoo defines the style "word-wrap" with value break-word, when I try to change it to "word-wrap: normal" the browser ignore it, also I tried to use "word-break: keep-all" style and yahoo parser deletes it, also I tried to wrap words with `<nobr>` tag and yahoo parser deletes them too. Email template looks good in all mobile clients except yahoo.

[image]

Comment: did u try with !important keyword.

Comment: Yes, and it didn't help

Comment: can you provide work code what you have tried.

Comment: <tr><td style="line-height:18px; word-wrap: normal !important;">We've identified new job listings that were posted today matching your background. Take a look at this list of positions and apply to any that interest you.</td>
 </tr>

Comment: This variant also not work:  <tr>
                                    <td style="line-height:18px;">
                                        <p style="word-wrap: normal !important">We've identified new job listings that were posted today matching your background. Take a look at this list of positions and apply to any that interest you.
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

Comment: try with spacing white-space: nowrap; still exists add some working example like fiddle.

Comment: A little late reply but try word break break all. It might fix your issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found to fix it to wrap each word in span and mention in yahoo media style "white-space: pre"